# How to properly return nested one-to-many data in ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `MinionLeaders` table with **one-to-many** relationship with `Minions` table. A minion could lead n-minions or it could lead itself if it doesn't have any member.

The problem is when I tried to GET a list of Minion Leaders with its members as json, it returns a disorganized-unfinished json :

```
[
    {
        "LeaderID":"ABCD000000000001",
        "Name":"Foo",
        "Members":
            [
                {
                    "ID":"EEEE000000000001",
                    "Name":"Fubar",
                    "LeaderID":"ABCD000000000001"
```

Also, the server throws an error :

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'minionLeader' with type 'rt5_app.Models.MinionLeaders'. Path '[0].Members[0]'.
```

How to properly return the data?

---

And here's how I fetch the data from database `MinionLeadersRepository.cs`:

```cs
 public async Task<IEnumerable<MinionLeaders>> ListAsync()
        {
            return await context.MinionLeaders.Include(p => p.Members)
                                              .ToListAsync();
        }
```

`ApiController.cs` :

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<MinionLeaders>> ListAsync()
        {
            return await _minionLeaders.ListAsync();
        }
```

`MinionLeadersModel.cs`

```cs
public class MinionLeaders
    {
        [Key]
        [MinLength(16)]
        [MaxLength(16)]
        public string LeaderID { get; set; }
        
        [MinLength(16)]
        [MaxLength(16)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Minion> Members { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out that this was a serializer problem.
I resolved it by setting the serializer settings to ignore loop references in `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

But I'm not sure if this is the real solution or just a workaround.